# Updating ECS task definition image using Codeship

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, codeship

I'm trying to determine the best way to generate a new or update an existing *AWS ECS* task definition JSON file using Codeship's `codeship/aws-deployment` image.

I don't want to rely on the implicit `:latest` tag within my task definition and wish to use the custom image tag generated in a previous step which pushes to *AWS ECR*.

Is a custom bash or python script to pull the current task definition, increment the version and replace the image string the only way to accomplish this or is there an existing CLI tool I'm glossing over?